# React doesn't issue any error but html file still doesn't get the rendered html from react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dom, jsdom

So I was trying to send this rendered HTML to the staff-home.html. It seems like the path specified in JSDOM.fromFile is correct because I console logged the html div which would receive the react element and it shows as below. However, my target html still doesn't show the sent react element.
[image]
[image]

**This is my project tree:**

```html
app
├── .DS_Store
├── Dockerfile
├── HTMLTableSamples.csproj
├── Properties
|   └── AssemblyInfo.cs
├── app.js
├── bin
|   └── www
├── database.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── pages
|   ├── login.html
|   ├── staff-home.html
|   ├── staff-list.html
|   └── user-list.html
├── public
|   ├── images
|   ├── javascripts
|   └── stylesheets
|       ├── bootstrap.css
|       ├── bootstrap.css.map
|       ├── bootstrap.js
|       ├── bootstrap.min.css
|       ├── bootstrap.min.js
|       ├── jquery-1.11.0.min.js
|       └── style.css
├── routes
|   ├── index.js
|   ├── login.js
|   ├── staffs.js
|   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── .DS_Store
    ├── error.ejs
    ├── index.ejs
    ├── report.ejs
    ├── user-list.html
    └── users-form.ejs
```

**This is my index.js:**

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var reactElement = React.createElement('h1', { className: 'header' }, 'This is React');

JSDOM.fromFile('/usr/src/app/pages/staff-home.html').then(function(dom) {
    var window = dom.window;
    global.document = window.document;
    global.window = window;
    console.log(document.getElementById('root'));
    ReactDOM.render(reactElement, document.getElementById('root'));
    console.log(document.getElementById('root'));
    
});

module.exports = router;
```

**This is my staff-home.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css' />
    <script src="/stylesheets/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Customer List</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button type="button" id="staffList" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Staff List
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button type="button" id="customerList" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Customer List
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**And this is my app.js:**

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var staffsRouter = require('./routes/staffs');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'routes')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/staffs', staffsRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/', express.static('pages'));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` is asynchronous. Have you tried to do the `console.log` in the callback method?

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the advice! I tried that and indeed, the callback wasn't executed. Do you have any idea what may cause this?